# Limiting access to data in a multi-tenant app

Tags: php

I am currently building a job search site on that a company can post and edit their jobs.
The problem is that i don't know how to query/limit a logged in company to edit only the jobs that they added to the site. Can anyone help? Please.

Comment: The answers below are really quite helpful, however giving us a bit of the database schema information will help yield a specific answer for your context.

Comment: hi, below are the query i am using. 


$query = "SELECT j.job_id, job, title, description 
      FROM jobs AS j, job_association AS ja 
      WHERE j.job_id = ja.job_id
      AND ja.job_category_id=$type
      AND ja.approved = 'Y' 
      ORDER BY date_submitted DESC";
 
$result = mysql_query ($query); 

When a user logged in as company to edit job, they can edit job they posted and also jobs other company posted, which is lack of security.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($loggedIn === true && $_SESSION['Company'] === true) {
    $_SESSION['CompanyID'] = $query['CompanyID'];
}

...

$CompanyID = $_SESSION['CompanyID'];

SELECT Job, Title, JobID
FROM Jobs
WHERE Company = '$CompanyID'
```

Comment: hi, below are the query i am using. 

$query = "SELECT j.job_id, job, title, description 
     FROM jobs AS j, job_association AS ja 
     WHERE j.job_id = ja.job_id 
     AND ja.job_category_id=$type 
     AND ja.approved = 'Y' 
     ORDER BY date_submitted DESC"; 


$result = mysql_query ($query); 

When a user logged in as company to edit job, they can edit job they posted and also jobs other company posted, which is lack of security.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a database question.

1. Do you have a table for companies, is there a unique key in the database for each company?
2. If so, I presume you have a table for jobs?

So you need to add a column to jobs with the id of the company the job posting belongs too. If you want to be able to lookup by company id, I reccomend going into MySql and creating an [index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Once you've figured that out, you can use a query such as the one suggested by @Jared.

Comment: hi.. i do have table for companies and also the column of company id in jobs table. i just can't let the logged company to see only the jobs they posted..

Answer (score 0):

Add a FK on the jobs table with the PK of the company table. That's how you'll know who created them.